# QML console.log() and console.debug() don't write to console

Tags: qt, qml, fedora

I'm using Qt 5.6 on Fedora 23 and I noticed that `console.log()` and `console.debug()` don't write anything to console. My example code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.warn("warn completed")
            console.log("log completed")
            console.error("error completed")
            console.debug("debug completed")
            console.exception("exception completed")
            console.info("info completed")
        }
    }
}
```

prints to console:

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
qml: warn completed
qml: error completed
qml: exception completed
onCompleted (qrc:/main.qml:16)
qml: info completed
```

so `warn`, `error`, `exception`, and `info` work fine. What am I doing wrong?

Edit #1: 
Project is freshly created, all my sources:

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

project.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
```

Edit #2:
Compile Output from Qt Creator shows that there are no `QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT`, `QT_NO_INFO_OUTPUT`, or `QT_NO_WARNING_OUTPUT`:

```
14:43:36: Running steps for project project...
14:43:36: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
14:43:36: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../project -I. -I../../Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include -I../../Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtQuick -I../../Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I../../Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtQml -I../../Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtNetwork -I../../Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I../../Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../project/main.cpp
/home/krzys/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/bin/rcc -name qml ../project/qml.qrc -o qrc_qml.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../project -I. -I../../Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include -I../../Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtQuick -I../../Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I../../Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtQml -I../../Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtNetwork -I../../Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I../../Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o qrc_qml.o qrc_qml.cpp
g++ -Wl,-z,origin -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN -Wl,-rpath,/home/krzys/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/lib -o project main.o qrc_qml.o   -L/home/krzys/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Quick -lQt5Gui -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
14:43:37: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
14:43:37: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

Comment: Did you build in release or debug mode? info/debug are translated to qDebug, I think, which can be disabled when built in release mode.

Comment: According to the documentation, `qDebug()`, `qInfo()`, and `qWarning()` are debugging tools. They can be compiled away by defining `QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT`, `QT_NO_INFO_OUTPUT`, or `QT_NO_WARNING_OUTPUT` during compilation.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: my Qt Creator (3.6.1) offers three builds: Debug, Profile, Release, and I tried all three with the same outcome.
@Tarod: I used freshly created project and I didn't add any custom defines to sources or `project.pro` file. 
Question is edited to include all the sources.

Comment: It looks like you're using a prebuilt Qt, which are always release builds. The Debug and Release build modes in Creator only change what *your project* is built with, not Qt itself. I don't think any of that matters though, as I do get the log/debug output with a prebuilt Qt. I would suggest building Qt yourself and stepping into the sources to see what's happening.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fedora 22 and later disables Qt debug output by default [1]. You can enable Qt debug output by modifying the system-wide `/etc/xdg/QtProject/qtlogging.ini` or by creating a user-specific configuration file `~/.config/QtProject/qtlogging.ini` for example with the following contents:

```
[Rules]
*.debug=true
```

1. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1227295

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the bug report, description and comments under it explain whole problem. Rule `*.debug=true` alone enabled tons of QT library logs, but adding `qt.*.debug=false` fixed it.

tldr; configuration below saved in `~/.config/QtProject/qtlogging.ini` fixed the debug problem.
`[Rules] *.debug=true; qt.*.debug=false`

Comment: This also was needed on MacOS (13.6) with Qt Design Studio 4.3.2 to see the console.log() output in the 'Application Output' pane.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of enabling Debug logging system wide like **jpnurmi** suggests in the   [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37906563/9231680). You can simply set a system variable to get the debug messages to show up in the console. [Qt Wiki about Logging Rules](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html#logging-rules)

To set it for one single execution of your app or qmlscene/qhot qml-preview. If you are starting them from the commandline:

```
$ QT_LOGGING_RULES="*.debug=true; qt.*.debug=false" your_executable
$ QT_LOGGING_RULES="*.debug=true; qt.*.debug=false" qmlscene/qhot main.qml
```

Or to set it for this session only (will be unset after reboot). And should be respected even if you launch/test from QtCreator or other IDE:

```
$ export QT_LOGGING_RULES="*.debug=true; qt.*.debug=false"
```

And then just start/test your executable or qmlscene/qhot normally

**Why is this better?**

Setting the logging rules systemwide will mean all **Qt apps you run will write debug messages to their logfiles**. I discovered a few log files that were **gigabytes** in size because the apps were accumulating a huge amount debug messages in their logs during normal usage.

Answer (score 2):

I found a more convenient solution by adding one of the two - depending
on if you use Qt Quick 1 or 2 to the pro file (rebuild and run QMake again)
according to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-debugging.html:

```
Qt Quick 1: CONFIG+=declarative_debug
Qt Quick 2: CONFIG+=qml_debug
```

To put it in your code it would look like:

project.pro

```c++
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick
CONFIG += c++11 qml_debug #or CONFIG+=declarative_debug for QtQuick 1

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
```

Now it might look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in a project that uses a tool like log4cplus the configure loggers, the `console.x` functions will be filtered through that tool as well as part of the `Qt` logger. So if logging is configured to only log error level messages you will have to use `console.error()` for the message to make it to the console.